# MVC using ASP.NET Identity Individual Accounts - How to Add Security Questions?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-identity

Here is my Scenario:

I need to capture at least 3 security questions & Answers as a part of user registration for an Website (Built in MVC 5 using Individual User Accounts as means of Authentication). Which I can do by extending ApplicationUser object.

So far so good.

I would like to ask these questions in the password recovery process.

I didn't find any support for security questions in ASP.NET Identity framework.

My Question:

Do I need to implement security questions out side of built in UserStore library or is there existing support similar to Secret questions in ASP.NET Membership functionality in .NET 2.0?

Note: Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 4):

To do this in ASP.Net Identity, you treat the answers as custom passwords.

Use `userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(Answer1);` to generate a hash for each answer to store in custom class properties/fields in the database. (Where userManager is the instance of the Identity UserManager)

On recovery, use

```
var verification = userManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(dbHash, Answer1);
```

to verify the challenge.

You can then check if `verification.Success` is true for each answer.

ref: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.ipasswordhasher.verifyhashedpassword(v=vs.111).aspx)

Comment: I think you answered my question. I wanted to know if there is built in support for storing security questions themselves. I ended up building custom class for my security questions/Answers but I like the idea of using the PasswordHasher for answers.

Comment: There isn't any built-in support or more automated fashion for storing security questions. It is possibly due to the fact that it can be argued that security questions are a bad form of security due to being passwords (answers) with hints (questions), especially if the questions are too easy. Though, sometimes security questions are what the person paying you demands.. and _sometimes_ having three good questions can be pretty secure. It seems Identity focuses more on two-factor authentication as being the choice of extending password recovery.